# Move marker dynamically

Tags: javascript, openlayers, layer, markers

I am using `Openlayers.Layer` and `OpenLayers.Marker` to display a marker on the map.

It is positioned correctly and I can successfuly show it and hide it doing:

`marker.display(boolean);`

But I try to **change its position** before displaying it but with no success. I already tried this:

```
var projections = {
    g: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    p: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")
};
var newlonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(newlon, newlat).transform(projections.g, projections.p);
```

```
marker.lonlat = newlonlat
layer.redraw();
```

(no errors triggered but position does not change)

and also tried this:

```
var px = map.getPixelFromLonLat(newlonlat);
marker.moveTo(px);
layer.redraw();
```

(it throws an error inside `getPixelFromLonLat` function. Error: `c is null`)

Why can't I **move markers dynamically** and what is the best way to do it?

#### Edit:

Maybe the problem resides in my position projection transformation when using second option:
`new OpenLayers.LonLat(newlon, newlat).transform(projections.g, projections.p);`

#### Edit 2

So, going deeper I found that `marker.map` property was `null`, so after its initialization I did:

```
var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(lonlat, icon);
marker.map = map;
```

where map is an `OpenLayers.Map` object and now its working fine. Don't know why but it fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To workaround the problem I did:

```
marker.lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(newlon, newlat);
layer.removeMarker(marker);
layer.addMarker(marker);
layer.redraw();
```

It seems stupid removing and adding the same marker to just update its position but it works. It may be slower when doing this to a large group of markers though.

Answer (score 2):

marker.moveTo works fine for me:

```
 var px = map.getPixelFromLonLat(new OpenLayers.LonLat(newLon,newLat));
 marker.moveTo(px);
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: A marker that moves 10° east on clicking: http://jsfiddle.net/Kenny806/vp7p3/ If there is any problem with this, let me know

Comment: @letiagoalves Edited the fiddle, now the marker is running away from mouse cursor :-) If you still can't get your code working, post it here and I am sure we will figure it out.

Comment: before using `map.getPixelFromLonLat` I need to do `new OpenLayers.LonLat(newlon, newlat).transform(projections.g, projections.p)` and I think that is making the problem

Comment: Which projections are you transferring between? I tried this for EPSG 4326 and 4324 and it seems to work. See function randomLonLat in http://jsfiddle.net/Kenny806/A2wE5/

Comment: you can see projections in the question. Map is created with those projections too.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice that. See http://jsfiddle.net/Kenny806/A2wE5/3/ . Changes are in the map object (added projection property) and in the randomLonLat function (just the projection codes changed here). Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: +1 for your effort. I found what the problem was but still don't know why it happens. see edit 2.

Comment: Good to hear you solved it:-) The solution made me think: did you add the marker to the map? ( `map.addMarker(marker);` ). Otherwise, I have no idea how this could happen.

Comment: Well, I added the marker to the layer and I also added the layer to the map.

Comment: No idea what could have gone wrong then. I guess the problem will be somewhere else then marker moving though, because you are using exactly the same methods for that as I do, and there seems to be no problem with that at all. If you still want to dig in it, post a larger snippet of your code so we can find what is causing the problem. Otherwise, have a nice day :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
marker.lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(newlon, newlat);
layer.drawMarker(marker);
```

(not testet)